# Pseudo element not appearing in IE 8

Tags: html, css

I have an :after pseudo element on a  element that *should* be working correctly.

My styles look like this:

```
.featured-video-link {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; 
}
.featured-video-link:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
  -o-transition: opacity .2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -51px;
  margin-top: -51px;
  width: 102px;
  height: 101px;
  opacity: .5;
  background: url(img/play-large.png); 
}
.featured-video-link:hover:after {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="featured-video">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="featured-video-link">
        <img src="featured-video.jpg" class="featured-video-image" alt="Characteristics of a Design Engineer">
    </a>
    <div class="featured-video-title">Characteristics of a Design Engineer</div>
</div>
```

In the IE 8 developer tools the height attribute is somehow getting mangled into being in the same line as the background attribute and the content and top attributes share a line as well. If I remove the top attribute, the element appears, but obviously in the wrong position and there is no reason for the top attribute to get placed where it is. The z-index seems to be factoring in as well.

Comment: Do you have a `<!DOCTYPE>` declared?

Comment: Did you try a display:block on the image? And what about leaving out the transition and opacity part? Does that brings you any closer to a solution?

Comment: The image is display:block. I've worked around the issue by inserting a <span> element on which I've attached the pseudo elements. I think it has to do with a z-index bug in IE8.